# How to set the page color of pdf output of Rmarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I am searching around here to add a page color to pdf output of Rmarkdown but couldn'tfind any possible way to do. Is it possible to change the page color of pdf output of Rmarkdown? If yes, how to add color to the page? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by page color?! page background color or font color?! Would you please clarify that?!

Comment: page background color @shafee

Comment: see my answer, does it solve your problem?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change page background color, you can do this by using `xcolor` **LaTex package**. Before the section header, for example, here before the line `## R Markdown`, you can specify the yellow as the background color of that page using `\pagecolor{yellow}`. Also you can define hex color in header-includes using `\definecolor{color-name}{HTML}{hex-code}` and use that defined color as page background color, as I defined `mybgcolor` here for the next page. (**Note that**, hex-color-code must contain all letters in **CAPITAL**)

````
    ---
    title: "Page color"
    author: "Shafee"
    date: '2022-07-15'
    output: pdf_document
    header-includes:
      - \usepackage{xcolor}
      - \definecolor{mybgcolor}{HTML}{97F0AF}
    ---
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```
    
    \pagecolor{yellow}
    ## R Markdown
    
    This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
    
    \newpage
    
    \pagecolor{mybgcolor}
    ## Including Plots
    
    You can also embed plots, for example:
    
    ```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
    plot(pressure)
    ```
    
    Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

**Rendered pdf output**

Now 1st page looks like this

[image: yellow-color-background]

and 2nd page looks like this

[image: greenish custom defined color background]

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can we add background image instead of page color to pdf (say first page)? And also how can we set opacity of the background image so that text that we put is properly visible @shafee

Comment: @Rich, please ask one question at a time. Also I think to do these, you need to find at first how to do this in latex and then you can use those latex code in your Rmd file ([see here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-preamble.html) how to add attach latex code in Rmd)

Comment: And if you fail to find by yourself, you are welcome to ask question separately along with whatever you tried to do before asking questions. Also there's a designated [site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for asking latex related question.